# Method chaining seems to break this d3 code. Why?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This is making me feel exceptionally stupid, but I was messing around with D3js(v4) today, and I am seeing some unexpected behavior regarding the behavior of method chaining.

[For this example](https://codepen.io/mwvanmeurs/pen/dzmbBw) everything works as expected -- great!

Below is an example of the code that works:

```
function render (data) {

  const circles = svg.selectAll('circle').data(data);

  circles.enter().append('circle').attr("r", circleRadius)
    .attr("class", "vote")
    .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x})
    .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y});

  circles.exit().remove();
}
```

---

[However, in this example](https://codepen.io/mwvanmeurs/pen/QMmWwG), I ended the `circle` chain to start a new one, and everything breaks.

Below is an example of the problematic code:

```
function render (data) {

  const circles = svg.selectAll('circle').data(data);

  circles.enter().append('circle').attr("r", circleRadius);

    circles
    .attr("class", "vote")
    .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x})
    .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y});

  circles.exit().remove();
}
```

Im sure this is something simple that I am missing, but I really feel like my not understanding this causes me to question some of my fundamental knowledge of JavaScript.

What's more, I'm even more bewildered because I was following along to an example tutorial on youtube. Here is a screenshot of this guys working code that does the same thing I was doing by breaking the chain, but his code works:[image] which can be seen in [this youtube video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8jvoTV54nXw&t=3511s)

What the heck am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't feel dumb — I think everyone who uses d3 does this at some point (me repeatedly).

What's happening is that `enter()` is returning the selection made when you add data. Everything you chain after `enter()` will be called on the appended circle created with the `enter()` selection. That's why your first example works.

When you break chain however, you are now calling `attire()` on the original selection, which won't work. It's equivalent to doing this:

```
const circles = svg.selectAll('circle').data(data)
.attr("cx", function (d) { return ( xScale(d.x) )})
.attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y});
```

To separate them you need to make a new selection:

```
d3.selectAll('circle')
.attr("cx", function (d) { return ( xScale(d.x) )})
.attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y});
```

This is a nice way to separate things that will need to be updated.

p.s. I think the reason the youtube video works is because he's using the old version of D3. In the new version, selections are immutable. See the first section here: https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/releases/tag/v1.0.0

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining that to me! I thought the versioning might be part of it, but wasn't sure.